# search and replace substring in string in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following task:
I have to replace several links, but only the links which ends with .do

Important: the files have also other links within, but they should stay untouched.

```
<li><a href="MeinKonto.do">Einstellungen verwalten</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="<s:url action='MeinKonto'/>">Einstellungen verwalten</a></li>
```

So I have to search for links with .do, take the part before and remember it for example as $a , replace the whole link with

```
<s:url action=' '/>
```

and past $a between the quotes.

I thought about sed, but sed as I know does only search a whole string and replace it complete.
I also tried bash Parameter Expansions in combination with sed but got severel problems with the quotes and the variables.

```
cat  ./src/main/webapp/include/stoBox2.jsp | grep -e '<a href=".*\.do">' | while read a;
do
    b=${a#*href=\"};
    c=${b%.do*};
    sed -i 's/href=\"$a.do\"/href=\"<s:url action=\'$a\'/>\"/g' ./src/main/webapp/include/stoBox2.jsp;
done;
```

any ideas ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are your links always surrounded by double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i  sed 's#href="\(.*\)\.do"#href="<s:url action='"'\1'"'/>"#g' ./src/main/webapp/include/stoBox2.jsp
```

Use patterns with parentheses to get the link without `.do`, and here single and double quotes separate the sed command with 3 parts (but in fact join with one command) to escape the quotes in your text.

```
 's#href="\(.*\)\.do"#href="<s:url action='

 "'\1'"

 '/>"#g'
```

parameters `-i` is used for modify your file derectly. If you don't want to do this just remove it. and save results to a tmp file with `> tmp`.

Comment: If you have several links on a same line, and if one of it, other than the first one, is a `.do` to modify, your regex will delete links (`sed` is greedy, and your parenthesis catch as much as possible). No offense, but what's wrong with my solution, that made you post nearly the same?

Comment: @Qeole Have you check your command? It just missed some double quotes or single quotes. And I think here you have \1 for `href="` is a little redundant.

Comment: The `href="` thing does not not look that redundant too me, but OK. For the quotes, yes I checked my command, and for me with OP's example, it provides desired output. Could you please provide more details? Did *you* tried your command with input as described in my first comment?

Comment: @Qeole yes, you're right in the first comment, I should add a `[^\"]` to avoid it. And for your command I just met error as `Unmatched ".`

Comment: I didn't meet this error. If you still have the exact command you typed, or if you (or anyone else) ever reproduces it, I'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
sed -i "s%\(href=\"\)\([^\"]\+\)\.do%\1<s:url action='\2'/>%g" \
    ./src/main/webapp/include/stoBox2.jsp;
```

You can capture patterns with parenthesis (`\(,\)`) and use it in the replacement pattern.
Here I catch a string without any `"` but preceding `.do` (`\([^\"]\+\)\.do`), and insert it without the `.do` suffix (`\2`).

There is a `/` in the second pattern, so I used `%`s to delimit expressions instead of traditional `/`.